Text Blender error
The letter Q gets inverted when I write with blender. I think I'm doing the right thing. First create text.
Puts gemoetry on the text.
Conventions text to mesh.
Clicks on the object the text should be on and selects the modifier Boolean.
All text will be correct without the letter Q.
Tested rewrite, import export object.




It's hard to tell what's causing this, maybe the normals are facing the wrong way. Please share a .blend file or provide more details.

It Is probably just boolean error ... It Is too complicated for such operation ... It Is more Common to use a normal or bump texture for such effect ... Or microdisplacement for really detailed shoot.

I would also check if normals are facing the wrong way as @KISKAart suggested. It looks like you are using the default Blender font, I wrote the same text down, converted it into a mesh and it works correctly. Have to set the modifier's Solver to Fast or Exact? Is the issue in both settings? Not only check the normals of your text but also the object with the Boolean modifier on. If that does not help, please upload your file at https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit the file into your question.

Another issue could be that after converting the text to a mesh object, the top and bottom faces are not merged with the side faces, i.e. you have open meshes there. This can cause problems with the Boolean modifier as well. Select all the text in Edit Mode and do M > Merge > By Distance.

Oh, and just a tip... I do not know how the geometry of your object looks like where you want to engrave your text into, but if it is just a simple plain big face, the resulting geometry might be very messy and chaotic. To get a slightly better result and maybe even make the Boolean modifier work better, it is sometimes helpful to pre-cut the face with supporting edges, in this example I made 13 cuts, one for each line of text: plain face vs. pre-cut faces

Uploaded the file. Had to cut down on the resolution to be able to post it..

The Normals look okej

(Using Blender 3.6.8)
It seems that there are some issues with the cut mesh at the part shown in red in the following picture, at the bottom of the letter Q:

It requires to activate Solver Options / Hole Tolerant in the Boolean modifier.
Next pictures are a zoom "inside" the mesh of letter Q showing an extra face protruding the wrong side:



The issue is coming from the curve of letter Q and it can not be solved before it is converted to a mesh. The mesh of letter Q can be edited to merge the two nodes (2 at the bottom and 2 at the top of each Q letter) as follows to remove the wrong face:

The Hole Tolerant option is not required after this modification.

Yay, it work. Have try to fix it for 4 hours. Thanks :D
